# Index with Include in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What's the difference between

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (A) INCLUDE (B,C)
```

and

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (A,B,C)
```

And what `SELECT` query will show me this difference?

Comment: This would be better asked on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) for questions on how a DBMS works.

Comment: You can check here http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-indexes/sql-server-indexes-with-included-columns/

Comment: This is explained in the docs already. `INCLUDE` means those columns aren't part of the index at all. They are included to make SELECT's that use the indexed columns faster. If you try to *filter* by A and B, the first query will be slower

Comment: [Create Indexes with Included Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, you mean, if I create both Indexes and will try 
SELECT A,B,C FROM TABLE1 WHERE A>5 (for example) 
the first index will be faster then the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please be aware of the order of the columns in my indexes, is slightly different than yours!*

TLDR; - scroll to the rule of thumb at the end of the answer, if you're not patient enough to read the answer.

Scenario #1:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (A,B,C)
```

Here all of the values in the 3 columns, A, B and C will be part of the search key. Hence, if your query is written like:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 1
   AND B = 0
   AND C = 3;
```

or similar, then it will use the index, because all of the columns by which you filter are part of the index **KEY** (A, B, C columns).

However, in the second scenario (*please notice that the B columns is in the first paranthesis, the one that identifies the **index KEY***):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (B) INCLUDE (A,C)
```

using a slightly different query, where we do not filter by the **index key**, in this case the "B" column:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TABLE
WHERE A = 1
   AND C = 0;
```

Our query will not use the index and will cause a FULL table scan.

The point here is, that if you always write a query where you filter by the columns in the INDEX KEY, then your index will be used an your query will run faster!

In the `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (B) INCLUDE (A,C)` scenario the following distinctions need to be understood:

```
- B - index KEY (only the values in the B column are used to build the structure of the search tree)
- A, C - values included along with the index KEY (they are not used in deciding the structure of the search tree, they are attached/included at each leaf level, along with the index KEY so that you do not have to do a lookup for these column values)
```

If we have the following table with data, if we create the index from the **2nd scenario**, like below:

[image]

Then the search tree structure that is created behind the scenes, that will support your filter (WHERE) query, will look like below:

[image]

---

**As a rule of thumb:**

If you ever have to write a query like:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM table
WHERE B = 0;
```

it is better to create an index like: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (B) INCLUDE (A,C)`

But if you ever have to write a query like:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM table
WHERE A = 0
   AND B = 1
   AND C = 3;
```

Then it is better to create an index like `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (A,B,C)`

Comment: And in which case is better to use the second case with include? When it is faster/better then just putting everything like that CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NAME1 ON TABLE1 (A,B,C)

Comment: @PopeyeTheSailor I updated my answer which will hopefully clarify this

Comment: as I understand the second one doesn't store all values in leafs of the tree and that's why it's better for the query in which we filter only by one variable, right?

Comment: @PopeyeTheSailor it stores the included values in the leaf, but it does not speed up search, because those values are only in the leaf and don't influence the structure of the tree. If the 11, 12, 32, 44 etc. values would be part of the index key, then they would make the search tree look differently, making it wider and possibly taller. Because of that, if you need to look at more values when traversing the tree, it will take you longer to reach the "destination" (answer).